# Unresolved dependency when assembly Spark 1.2.0

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying  to build Spark 1.2.0 on ubuntu   but i'm getting dependency issues.

I basically download the files extract the folder and run sbt/sbt/assembly

- **sbt = 0.13.6**
- **scala = 2.10.4**

> ```
> sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-
> network-common_2.10;1.2.0: configuration not public in 
> org.apache.spark#spark-network-common_2.10;1.2.0: 'test'. It was 
> required from org.apache.spark#spark-network-shuffle_2.10;1.2.0 test
> ```

Comment: what type of package did you download ? are you trying to build everything ? I've just build it with no particular issues... :-/

Comment: @OlivierGirardot   I see the same issues. I am v experienced with building spark back to 0.6 up to 1.3.0 rc.

Comment: on what os ? using sbt ? from which directory are you building ?

Comment: can you add the dependencies call from your sbt file?

Answer (score 0):

This [sbt issue](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1827) seems to explain it: this would be a consequence of trying to get a test->test dependency if the same version has been resolved out of a public Maven repository.

A workaround would be using git SHA versioning or SNAPSHOT for non final builds of that test dependency, but we won't know more unless we get an idea of how you got to a 'bad' ivy cache state.

TL;DR : try clearing your cache of spark artefacts before building.

Edit: This is fixed in sbt 0.13.10-RC1 https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/2345 Please update